Group Homomorphisms and Subgroup Presentations SageMath
I have a finitely presented group $G=\langle S \mid R\rangle$. I want to know if SageMath has any built-in functions for the following two tasks:

given a finite group $H$ and a map of sets $f: S\to H$, check if $f$ induces a group homomorphism $G\to H$ and return said homomorphism if it exists, and
produce a presentation for a finite-index subgroup given a generating set (e.g. using Reidemeister-Schreier).

For a little more context, given knot group $\pi$ presented as a Wirtinger presentation, I want a presentation for the normal closure of a power of a meridian. Two (fairly clear) ways to obtain this group are

as the kernel of a homomorphism $\pi\to\mathbb{Z}/p$, and
as a subgroup with a specified list of generators.

it would be nice to avoid writing too much code from scratch. I have searched around in the Sage docs but haven't found anything that directly accomplishes what I want.
